# Can't dock a Dock Widget when used inside a Widget

Tags: qt

I've insert a Dock Widget inside a widget, and I want to Check the dock Checkbox inside the Designer in order for it to be docked. But this seems impossible to do since it is disabled like shown in the following picture:

[image]

I also tried the following line of Code:

```
ui->dockWidget->setAllowedAreas(Qt::BottomDockWidgetArea);
```

But it seems that it has no effect...

Answer (score 1):

The 'dock' property enabled in MainWindow Form
if you are using Widget, change it to MainWindow and dock will work properly